# Instancing an abstract class?

Tags: c#

```
public abstract class T
{
    public abstract IEnumerable<T> MakeOneMove();

    public IEnumerable<T> MakeOneMove(string evt)
    {
        List<T> returnList = new List<T>();
        IEnumerable<T> steps = MakeOneMove();
        foreach (T step in steps)
        {
            if (step.Event == evt)
            {
                returnList.Add(step);
            }
        }
        return returnList;
    }
```

and elsewhere the class is used like this:

```
            T currentImpl = pendingImpl.Pop();

            IEnumerable<T> nextImpl = currentImpl.MakeOneMove();
            foreach (ConfigurationBase next in nextImpl){

            }
```

I am confused about two things. It seems like class T is being instanced , but class T is an abstract class. I thought this wasn't possible. I thought only non-abstract subclasses of the abstract class could be instanced. Also, in the class, makeonemove() is called, but isn't the version with no arguments not overridden and therefore not defined? it seems to me like this code shouldn't compile, yet it does.

Answer (score 2):

> I am confused about two things. It seems like class T is being
>   instanced , but class T is an abstract class. I thought this wasn't
>   possible. I thought only the subclass could be instanced.

`abstract class T` is not being instantiated, rather it is just a pointer to a concrete implementation of the `abstract class`.

> Also, in the
>   class, makeonemove() is called, but isn't the version with no
>   arguments not overridden? it seems to me like this code shouldn't
>   compile, yet it does.

This is one of the benefits of using an Abstract Class. It allows you to provide a *"base"* implementation of its members that *can* be overridden in derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

No, The class `T` is abstract.  In the method call `T currentImpl = pendingImpl.Pop();` the T there just means that the object returned will be a type which derives from T, it effectively establishes (Declares) the type of the variable named `currentImpl`, not the type of the object itself.

The actual type of the object being instantiated will be whatever type `pendingImpl.Pop()` creates.  It looks like `Pop()` is what is called a factory method.  You would have to look at how it is implemented to see exactly what type is instantiates and returns.

Answer (score 0):

No, T just means that the class has to be convertible to T (ie it iherits from it and can be cast as T).

I suggest checking here to read up on inheritance:
http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/lesson08

And here to read about casting: 
http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/Lesson22

Essentially if a class inherits another, it can be cast into an instance of the class and is thus treated as that class for the cast.

So say I made a Class H that inherited from T, then cast it to T, for the duration of that cast, H would essentially be disguised as T and you could only access the elements it inherits from T. So say I gave H a function called 'MakeTwoMoves', then made an instance of H called 'hi' (eg H hi = new H();) I could call MakeOneMove and MakeTwoMoves. Once it is cast to T however (eg (T)H) you MakeTwoMoves is no longer accessible because it's not declared in T, it's something unique to H.

What this means for your code however is that pendingImpl most likely would contain an array of instances of classes that have inherited from T (like the H in my example). They are then cast inside the pop method (or possibly earlier, ie before being put in the internal array) and come out as T, so each instance could be a completely different class but the only thing you know about them is that they inherit from T.

I hope that cleared things up a bit, T isn't the most intuitive name to work with.